# SSH Client not working?

Tags: ssh

When I connect through SSH to my server via SSH, I am seeing something like this:

```
asd:/Users/asd () $ ssh root@47.52.32.36
Password for root@iZj6cdolljnt77ccercqzsZ:
<hangs for a while>
packet_write_wait: Connection to 47.52.32.36 port 22: Broken pipe
```

I thought this could be an issue with my SSH client so I downloaded vSSH client and was able to connect!

I've tried connecting via the ssh client on Terminal.app and iTerm.app but both times they seem to hang before reporting that there is a broken pipe.

How can I go about debugging why my SSH client is not connecting but vSSH is?

**EDIT**

This is my version: OpenSSH_7.3p1, LibreSSL 2.4.1

And this is the -v info:

```
vng:/Users/vng () $ ssh root@47.52.32.36
Password for root@iZj6cdolljnt77ccercqzsZ:
packet_write_wait: Connection to 47.52.32.36 port 22: Broken pipe
vng:/Users/vng () $ ssh -v root@47.52.32.36
OpenSSH_7.3p1, LibreSSL 2.4.1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 47.52.32.36 [47.52.32.36] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/vng/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/vng/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/vng/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/vng/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/vng/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/vng/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/vng/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/vng/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1_hpn13v11 FreeBSD-20140420
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1_hpn13v11 FreeBSD-20140420 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 47.52.32.36:22 as 'root'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:1/YIGlOXCfpqFM+0btV0zmALuc2JPVYgZ9aBGOn+KQE
debug1: Host '47.52.32.36' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/vng/.ssh/known_hosts:60
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/vng/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/vng/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/vng/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/vng/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
Password for root@iZj6cdolljnt77ccercqzsZ:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
Password for root@iZj6cdolljnt77ccercqzsZ:
debug1: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
Authenticated to 47.52.32.36 ([47.52.32.36]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
packet_write_wait: Connection to 47.52.32.36 port 22: Broken pipe
```

Comment: Please add your system and the ssh version (`ssh -V`)

Comment: Have you tried a different server to verify it's your client?  Also, many systems do not allow a root user to log in remotely; try with a different account.  Finally, issue the command with `-v` (lowercase v) to get *verbose* output of what's happening during the connection process.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host *
    IPQoS 0x00
```

Adding this solved my issue

Comment: Adding this to which file exactly? And what does it do?